# Replacing each element of any object

Tags: r, recursion

Is there any clever way to replace each part of *any* object with some values (for example `NA`'s).

Let's take those objects

```
obj1 <- t.test(1:10)
obj2 <- matrix(1:9, 3)
obj3 <- 1:10
obj4 <- list(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:5], c = as.factor(1:10))
```

the expected output would be similar to

```
for (i in 1:length(obj1)) obj1[[i]] <- rep(NA, length(obj1[[i]])) 
obj2 <- matrix(rep(NA, 9), 3)
obj3 <- rep(NA, 10)
obj4 <- list(a = rep(NA, 10), b = rep(NA, 5), c = rep(NA, 10))
```

So no matter if an object is a list, matrix, data.frame, vector etc. each part of the object is to be replaced with `NA`.

Is there any clever way to do so that does not need multiple loops, checking for object type every time and lots of exceptions (`if (is.list(part)) ...` etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that using an empty extraction index during assignment (i.e., `x[] <- NA`) replaces all elements with the right-hand side value. In your case, you could do something like this using `rapply` to attack all elements of all objects:

```
> rapply(mget(ls()), function(x) x[] <- rep(NA, length(x)), how = "replace")
$obj1
$obj1$statistic
[1] NA

$obj1$parameter
[1] NA

$obj1$p.value
[1] NA

$obj1$conf.int
[1] NA NA

$obj1$estimate
[1] NA

$obj1$null.value
[1] NA

$obj1$alternative
[1] NA

$obj1$method
[1] NA

$obj1$data.name
[1] NA


$obj2
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$obj3
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$obj4
$obj4$a
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$obj4$b
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

$obj4$c
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

That's a very simple solution, though. You could probably complicate the function being passed to `rapply` so that it used S3 method dispatch to identify what class of object it was seeing and possibly return a different data structure (e.g., data.frame or matrix) accordingly, rather than just a vector of `NA`s.